# Why is president Nixon considered worst president in the history of US?

Tags: united-states

I have listened from people that Nixon is considered the worst president of US.

I also watched a Doctor Who episode in which Nixon asks The Doctor whether he would be remembered or not. Then, The Doctor said that nobody would ever forget him. Later in behind the scenes, I found some guy from production team was laughing at this saying The Doctor made him even more worse.

Why is Nixon considered worst president of United States?

Comment: "considered" means this is intrinsically an opinion based question.  Considered by whom? the staff of Doctor Who?  The opinion of television writers tend to derive from what makes the best TV, not from extensive research.  (After all, they also believe that a sonic screwdriver can open all doors and hack all computers....)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace and they believe that pushing a partisan agenda equates unbiased newsmaking (and that's all journalists, irrespective of political leaning).

Comment: Knowing who, exactly, considers Nixon the worst president would both enlighten us on the credibility of that person, and enable the question to be answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Nixon is not usually considered the worst US president.

Presidential rankings are inherently subjective, and opinions often vary wildly for recent presidents, where they tend to fall along partisan lines. Sometimes opinions are highly convergent; Lincoln is often considered the best whilst the few preceding presidents the worst, all tied to how well they handled the secession and civil war. [Nixon, although ranking relatively low, does not appear last](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_rankings_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States).

What stands out about his tenure is the [Watergate scandal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal) which represented an unprecedented abuse of power and forced Nixon's resignation, the only US president to do so.

Comment: Looks like the last paragraph is the answer.

Comment: @SachinShekhar nope, the first paragraph is the answer. The worst president in US history is widely considered to be Obama by some, Carter by others, Bush Jr by yet others, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @jwenting My statement was around Doctor Who part. In that episode, Nixon's power abuse was displayed.

Comment: @SachinShekhar irrelevant, it's fiction. And every president can be linked to abusing his power at some point, somewhere in their careers. It doesn't make them "the worst president ever", they'd all be "the worst president ever".